# Javascript/jquery change css depending on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to create a script thant changes the css of a page, depending on a url inserted by the user.

For example

If I use this url: http://mypage.com/
It shows this css: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfolder/style.css">`

But I need if I use this url for example: http://mypage.com/#color1 (or another url format you consider is better to achieve the same)

I need to change it for the new css, based on the url, and overwrite it, showing this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfolder/user1.css">`

I need it uses the css based on the url, replacing the css file name.

This way if a user enters the site http://mypage.com/#color1 it will show the **blue.css** (changing everything to blue, change logo to blue...) and if enters http://mypage.com/#red, css changes to **red.css**, showing everything red, but the content is exactly the same.

Anyone has any idea how this can be done?

Comment: yes it is.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get your hash value you and load it.  If you are changing the # at runtime, you will need to make sure you delete the previous, but this is assuming you will just do this once.

```
var hash_var = window.location.hash;
if (hash_var){
    $("<link />").attr({
      rel:"styleheet", 
      type:"text/css",
      href:hash_var.substring(1) + ".css"
    }).appendTo("head");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Fallenreaper! I added this to the first part of my code, but it's not changing the css, what can I have done wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using?  ALSO:  check the javascript console, the Sources, to see if it is added to the sources?

Comment: ALSO: you need to make sure that it is IN the folder of the file.  You know? Some people store css files in a css folder.  You would want to make sure that the dir structure is correct

Comment: i posted 2 comments.  Read them and let me know what you see